# How to connect two raspberry pi zero w's to ond HDMI display

Tags: pi-zero-w, connection

Has anyone successfully connected two raspberry pi zero w's together to one HDM1 touch display (7" for example)?

Any tutorials available for this?

Answer (score 1):

An HDMI display can be shared between two devices using an HDMI splitter:

[image]

Sharing a touchscreen (a USB HID I assume) can be similarly done using a USB switch:

[image]

Comment: For my application, HDMI splitter will not work. I am making a portable solution. It has to be wired together and not by a bully splitter.

Comment: @ironmantis7x Perhaps you should explain in your question what exactly you want to achieve. It may turn out you don't even need to connect two RPis to one screen.

Comment: I want to make one lcd an input with a full screen keyboard and the other lcd the display.

Comment: @ironmantis7x Your question says you have 2 RPis and 1 LCD. Your comment says you have 2 LCDs. Which one is it?

Comment: One R-Pi, two LCDs